# Unable to create iOS static library .a file using make command

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, makefile

My Makefile is as the following and it gives error as make:

> No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

```
XBUILD=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
PROJECT_ROOT=/Users/AshrafMac/Desktop/iOSSDK/
PROJECT=$(PROJECT_ROOT)/InfColorPicker.xcodeproj
TARGET=/Users/AshrafMac/Desktop/iOSSDK/

all: libInfColorPickerSDK.a

libInfColorPicker-i386.a:
    $(XBUILD) -project $(PROJECT) -target $(TARGET) -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release clean build
    -mv $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/Release-iphonesimulator/lib$(TARGET).a $@

libInfColorPicker-armv7.a:
    $(XBUILD) -project $(PROJECT) -target $(TARGET) -sdk iphoneos -arch armv7 -configuration Release clean build
    -mv $(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/Release-iphoneos/lib$(TARGET).a $@

libInfColorPickerSDK.a: libInfColorPicker-i386.a libInfColorPicker-armv7.a
    xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -create -output $@ $^

clean:
    -rm -f *.a *.dll
```

Unable to create ios static library .a file using make command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> xcodebuild -project '**MyProject.xcodeproj**' -configuration 'Release'
>   -sdk '**iphoneos9.3**' clean build ARCHS='armv7 armv7s' IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='5.0' TARGET_BUILD_DIR='./build-arm'
>   BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR='./build-arm'
>
> xcodebuild -project '**MyProject.xcodeproj**' -configuration 'Release'
>   -sdk '**iphoneos9.3**' clean build ARCHS='arm64' IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='6.0' TARGET_BUILD_DIR='./build-arm64'
>   BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR='./build-arm64'
>
> xcodebuild -project '**MyProject.xcodeproj**' -configuration 'Release'
>   -sdk '**iphonesimulator9.3**' clean build ARCHS='i386' IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='5.0' TARGET_BUILD_DIR='./build-i386'
>   BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR='./build-i386'
>
> xcodebuild -project '**MyProject.xcodeproj**' -configuration 'Release'
>   -sdk '**iphonesimulator9.3**' clean build ARCHS='x86_64' VALID_ARCHS='x86_64' IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='6.0'
>   TARGET_BUILD_DIR='./build-x86_64' BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR='./build-x86_64'
>
> lipo -create './build-arm/**MyProject.a**'
>   './build-arm64/**MyProject.a**' './build-i386/**MyProject.a**'
>   './build-x86_64/**MyProject.a**' -output '**Mylibrary.a**'

**EXECUTE** the above code in **TERMINAL**.
In the above code **MyProject.xcodeproj** should be replaced with your Xcode project name and **iphoneos9.3** should be replaced by maximum supported deployment target by your Xcode (For Example I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and maximum supported deployment by it is 9.3 see in:  **YourProject >> target >>> General Tab**)

Comment: Hey @Ashraf using this linkhttps://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/#Installing_the_Xcode_Command_Line_Tools

I could not get make file in my xcode. where i may get that make file.?